# Laravel 4 and Backbone: JSON not posting to controller

Tags: json, backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having an issue with JSON not being posted to a controller in Laravel 4.  Here is the AJAX call in my Backbone event:

```
u = $('#username').val();
p = $('#password').val();

formData = {username: u, password: p};
console.log(formData);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/leads/public/login',
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

As you can see, there is a `console.log` and it correct logs my JSON object.  Also, in Firebug, I can see that the data is being posted.  But in my Laravel controller, I am not getting the JSON returned.

I can return a text string from the `store` method in my controller, but not `Input::json()`.  In fact, when I do that, there is no response from the server at all.  I feel like maybe I should be doing this in more of a Backbone way, rather than the AJAX jQuery call.  Is that where my problem is arising?

I have this Laravel route:

```
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@store');
```

Answer (score 1):

Should the route be

```
Route::post('/leads/public/login', 'LoginController@store');
```

Because you are posting to `url: '/leads/public/login'`?